# Trying to use LdapRecord with BackPack but without success

Tags: ldap, laravel-backpack

I am trying to add LDAP authentication to a BackPack-based application. I am following the same route as @realtebo here:
[How to use backpack-for-laravel with LdapRecord-Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66426767/how-to-use-backpack-for-laravel-with-ldaprecord-laravel)

The modified User Model looks like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use LdapRecord\Laravel\Auth\LdapAuthenticatable;
use LdapRecord\Laravel\Auth\AuthenticatesWithLdap;

class User extends Authenticatable implements LdapAuthenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;
    use Notifiable;
    use CrudTrait;
    use HasRoles;
    use AuthenticatesWithLdap;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

The configuration of the config.auth.providers looks like this:

```php
    'providers' => [
        // https://ldaprecord.com/docs/laravel/v2/auth/database/configuration#introduction
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'ldap',
            'model' => LdapRecord\Models\ActiveDirectory\User::class,
            'rules' => [],
            'database' => [
                'model' => App\Models\User::class,
                'sync_passwords' => false,
                'sync_attributes' => [
                    'name' => 'cn',
                    'email' => 'mail',
                ],
                'sync_existing' => [
                    'email' => 'mail',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

I have made sure to change the value of config.backpack.base.guard to null and also tried with 'web'. But unfortunately I still get this error: "These credentials do not match our records.".

The Ldap connection test returns success:

```
$ php artisan ldap:test
Testing LDAP connection [default]...
+------------+------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
| Connection | Successful | Username                             | Message                 | Response Time |
+------------+------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
| default    | ✔ Yes      | cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com | Successfully connected. | 209.32ms      |
+------------+------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
```

The logs from LdapRecord aren't of much use because this what I get:

```
[2022-02-02 11:59:34] local.INFO: LDAP (ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389) - Operation: Binding - Username: cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com  
[2022-02-02 11:59:34] local.INFO: LDAP (ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389) - Operation: Bound - Username: cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com  
[2022-02-02 11:59:34] local.INFO: LDAP (ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389) - Operation: Search - Base DN: dc=example,dc=com - Filter: (&(objectclass=\74\6f\70)(objectclass=\70\65\72\73\6f\6e)(objectclass=\6f\72\67\61\6e\69\7a\61\74\69\6f\6e\61\6c\70\65\72\73\6f\6e)(objectclass=\75\73\65\72)(email=\70\61\73\74\65\75\72\40\6c\64\61\70\2e\66\6f\72\75\6d\73\79\73\2e\63\6f\6d)(!(objectclass=\63\6f\6d\70\75\74\65\72))) - Selected: (objectguid,*) - Time Elapsed: 317.31
```

Additional note regarding the LDAP queries:
One thing I noticed about the LDAP query from the logs is that it uses the attribute *email* while the actual attribute in the directory is *mail*:

```
     [
       "objectclass" => [
         "count" => 4,
         0 => "inetOrgPerson",
         1 => "organizationalPerson",
         2 => "person",
         3 => "top",
       ],
       0 => "objectclass",
       "sn" => [
         "count" => 1,
         0 => "Pasteur",
       ],
       1 => "sn",
       "cn" => [
         "count" => 1,
         0 => "Louis Pasteur",
       ],
       2 => "cn",
       "uid" => [
         "count" => 1,
         0 => "pasteur",
       ],
       3 => "uid",
       "telephonenumber" => [
         "count" => 1,
         0 => "602-214-4978",
       ],
       4 => "telephonenumber",
       "mail" => [
         "count" => 1,
         0 => "pasteur@ldap.forumsys.com",
       ],
       5 => "mail",
       "count" => 6,
       "dn" => "uid=pasteur,dc=example,dc=com",
     ],
```

Brief update: making gradual progress; I realised the test LDAP server requires the OpenLDAP User model instead of ActiveDirectory. After changing the value for backpack.base.authentication_column to 'mail' and guard to 'web' the user can now authenticate.

Now this Exception is thrown:

```
Call to undefined method LdapRecord\Query\Model\OpenLdapBuilder::getTable() (View: /project_directory/vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/base/inc/menu_user_dropdown.blade.php)
```

It look as if the LdapRecord User Model need to be modified. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi @slooffmaster, By any chance did you get a solution for this. Thanks